# Task and Main Thread returns same Id?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Following code returns the same id, is it expected because Task should be running in a separate thread?

```
    private void frmSplash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());**

        var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            **MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());**

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();` which means that it will use Context for your UI thread.

Use `Task.Run()` or other `TaskScheduler` to have separate ThreadIDs

More details can be found on - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's because I want to update the UI, is there any other way where I can update the UI other than using TaskScheduler?

Comment: @Ali You can't update the UI from a non-UI thread.  That's pretty much true *by definition*.

Comment: @Servy actually I want to show the progress on the UI from worker threads.

Comment: @Ali Then use the `Progress` class, which is specifically designed to do *exactly* that.

Comment: @Servy I get your point and now understand the philosophy behind TPL, Thank you for explanation pal.

Comment: @ndd I accept your answer based on yours and Servy comments. Thanks for your help.